# Dictionary values not equal when using a variable vs direct value?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-requests

I'm working with an api right now that requires the following body to conduct a search:

```
data = {
        "field_filters": {
            "field_num": [
                "user.name"
            ]
        }
    }
```

When sent using this code, the search perfectly works:

```
response = requests.request('POST', APurl, headers=headers, json=data)
```

However, if I change the first block (with the data dictionary) to the following:

```
username = "user.name"
data = {
        "field_filters": {
            "field_num": [
                username
            ]
        }
    }
```

The api returns all of the users (which indicates that the search was invalid so it just returns a list of all users). No error code is returned, this api (assetpanda) kinda sucks.

Any ideas? My overall goal is making a function that will grab a user's info and parse the big api JSON response into a smaller one, which I can do, I just can't figure out how to pipe in that dictionary value to the function as a variable.

Comment: JSON print `data` in both cases, immediately before the requests call. Are they the same? If so, I don't see how they can trigger a different result (assuming headers etc. are identical).

Comment: I don't know why, but after taking a lunch and trying again it's working. I think this may be an issue with the API sometimes ignoring my search, weird. Will look into further